# Using Gitlab deploy keys with write access

Tags: ssh, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am currently running CE version 8.17.4 and am attempting to setup a deploy key with write access (as of 8.16) so that my runner instance may commit build artifacts back to the repository. I took the following steps to set this up:

- On the runner instance, I generated the ssh keypair with the command:

  `sudo ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "label" -b 4096`
- The generated keypair was saved to **/home/gitlab-runner/.ssh/id_rsa** and password protected.
- Within Gitlab, I created a public deploy key from the admin console and pasted the contents of **id_rsa.pub** into the appropriate field and verified that the key fingerprints matched. I checked the "Write access allowed" box.
- In the private project that I wished to enable repository access from the runner, I enabled the newly created public deploy key.
- This is a LaTeX document respository, so in the **.gitlab-ci.yml** file, I issue the following script after building the pdf:

  `after_script:
    - "git commit -am 'autobuild PDF'"
    - "git push origin master"`

When the changes were committed, the build ran successfully on the runner up until the **git push origin master** command, and this error was thrown:

`fatal: Authentication failed for 'http://gitlab-ci-token:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@host/project.git/'`

Ok. A couple questions:

1. If the deploy key is just an SSH key, shouldn't it be connecting on the secure port or does this matter? I haven't found much documentation on *using* this new write-permission deploy key feature, so am I missing something in the steps I took above?
2. Do I need to include **[ci skip]** in the commit message to avoid looping CI builds? I saw this concern come up in the original issue tickets for this feature, but did not see whether this step was required or not.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: An ssh key is used to connect through ssh not http or https. You may need to define a new remote that connects through ssh `git add remote ssh_remote git@host:user/project.git` then push to that remote `git push ssh_remote master`

Comment: probably too late but you probably want artifacts instead of commits

Answer (score 1):

Jawad's comment worked for me: you need to force SSH. for example

```
git remote add ssh_remote git@host:user/project.git
git push ssh-remote HEAD:dev
```

thanks jawad

Comment: Shouldn't it be `git remote add ssh_remote git@host:user/project.git` instead?